# ReactJS Additional Select property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a select value property which is {board.id}, but i also need to acess the {board.name}, any way i could make another property to work?

I´ve made the example={board.name} but without sucess..

```js
   handleChange(event){
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.setState({example: event.target.example});
    }


let boards = this.state.boards;
let optionItems = boards.map((board) =>
<option key={board.id} value={board.id} example={board.name} >{board.name}</option>);


<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="custom-select dropbox">
   {optionItems}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for you.

```
class App extends Component {
  handleChange(event){
    let index = event.target.selectedIndex;
    let el = event.target.childNodes[index]
    let option =  el.getAttribute('example');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select value={'test'} onChange={this.handleChange} className="custom-select dropbox">
        <option value={'test1'} example={'testKey1'}>Test1</option>
        <option value={'test2'} example={'testKey2'}>Test2</option>
        <option value={'test3'} example={'testKey3'}>Test3</option>
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

You forgot that you need the index of the option.

Answer (score 1):

Sasha that will just return the example attribute of the select field itself, not the option's example attribute.

Comment: yep, didnt think that in event target will be <select>, not <option>

Comment: I got confused the first time too, since I used to work with jQuery in the past quite a lot and you know how it is there regarding of the onChange event that you just do $(this).val(), and you are all set :D

Answer (score 1):

```
class App extends React.Component {

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { selectedIndex, options } = e.target;
    const selectedOption = options[selectedIndex];
    console.log('NAME: ' + selectedOption.dataset.name)
    console.log('VALUE: ' + selectedOption.value)

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <select 
          onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value=''>-select option-</option>
          <option value='1' data-name='name1'>1</option>
          <option value='2' data-name='name2'>2</option>
          <option value='3' data-name='name3'>3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find full object by selected id:

```
handleChange(event) {
        const {boards} = this.props;
        const selectedBoard = boards.find((board) => board.id === event.target.value);
}
```